# Nested for loop in batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm pretty new with batch. I'm trying to run a nested for-loop. When I run it in command prompt, it works fine, but not in the script. (I know about the % | %% difference.)

```
for %%i in %list_with_service_names% do for /F "tokens=4" %%j in ('sc queryex %i ^| findstr STATE') DO echo %%i     %%j
```

Comment: What is this: `%list_with_service_names%`.  You are missing the opening and closing parentheses.

Comment: Oooooo.... thats it ... i was changing it so many times, that i got it wrong at the end. Thank you !!!!!

Comment: You should also change it to `SC QUERY`, there's no need to get the extended query information for just `STATE`

Comment: You mixed up the `%%` and `%` stuff in your code..

Comment: @Squashman: Seeing as that comment helped the asker. You should repost it as an answer